# Hey there I'm a beginner in particle physics trying to "selfstudy" from online resources. I want to ask how much of what I learned is correct?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, higgs

The information I have gained thus far regarding the standard model is;

1. fermions and how their intrinsic nature.
   they have half spin, non zero mass, a charge, a weak hypercharge (for leptons), a color charge (for quarks).
2. bosons and their intrinsic nature.
   they have integer spins, INITIALLY massless, charged... etc,etc

So my confusion lies in this "intrinsic mass" thing which I thoroughly (by which I mean browsing few channels and sites) researched. I figured out a simple model to help me understand by mashing all the data I learned to fit as one.
Particles like hadrons dont have entirely intrinsic mass. Most is simply kinetic energy. Regarding this intrinsic mass, I stumbled upon "higgs mechanism" which I have understood as follows:

For mass of bosons;
each gauge boson have their own vector fields and bosons are simply a disturbance in respective field. In the beginning they are all massless. Bosons being vector gauge fields that can undergo Local transformations will interact with ONLY scalar fields. The only scalar field in the standard model is owned by none other than higgs field. Initially this higgs field is in an empty state with high potential and unstable. If an external interference like vector fields were to give energy to such a system, the potential would drop to the lowest possible state. Thus, acquiring some Potential (which I heard being referred to as VEV). At this vacuum state the potential energy is min but kinetic remains max and there is oscillations. This oscillations about the vacuum state are infinitely many creating a condensate of higgs bosons. Particles like photons and gluons interact with such a field as if there is no interaction. They just move from one vacuum state to another no bueno. BUT some particles like electrons, quarks, W & Z bosons, when interacting with such a state of Higgs field causes fluctuations in the field itself. SO there is DEFINITELY interactions when it comes to the said particles. This interaction involves higgs boson to be absorbed and emitted continually from and to the condensate which slows down the relative motion of said particles. The more coupling strength they have, the less heavy they become. A higgs field has rotationally symmetric potential once the symmetry is broken. Does this mean one higgs field gives just one nambu-goldstone boson? and it gets absorbed by one previously mentioned particle to slow down action at ONE instant of TIME? I see no connection between condensates, eating a goldstone boson, breaking of a symmetry and its killing me T-T... Little knowledge is dangerous and im afraid im falling in the not so good direction lol. Little help regarding how far of what I mentioned is true would be really helpful!

for fermions; I assume mostly the same thing goes on where condensates of higgs particles slows motion through the vacuum state.

Comment: Please note that ["Am I right" questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/self-study-students-confirmation-type-questions) aren't very suitable for this site. Please try to rephrase your question so that it asks for an explanation about a specific physical concept. Asking "how much of what I learned is correct" as you currently do, can lead to answers of the sort "very little" or "very much", which won't be very interesting to many people, including I suspect you, as you may want to obtain more specific information and not only whether you're "right or wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you this but you have understood actually nothing about the standard model. I have the impression that you just grasped the correlation between terms, not what they do mean, like one usually do viewing divulgative youtube videos.

I'll do my best at explaining this without math for you in the most schematic way possible.

***FIELD CONTENT***

The standard model is built on gauge field theory and Poincare invariance.
You have a gauge group in the standard model which describe the field charge content and the Poincare covariance describe the spin content of the fields.
The gauge group is:

$G = SU(3) × SU_L(2) × U_Y(1)$

So you have 3 main charges:

-1: $SU(3)$ charge called **color charge**

-2: $SU_L(2)$ charge called **weak charge**

-3: $U_Y(1)$ charge called **hypercharge**

The color and weak charges can have multiple values on the same object, the hyper change has only a single value on a given object.
More on that later

**1) Gauge Fields:**

Those are described by antisymmetric rank 2 tensor fields, the so called **spin-1** **massless** representations of Poincare group.

For **each generator** of the Lie algebra associated to one component of the gauge group $G$ you have **a different massless gauge boson**, in what is called the adjoint representation of the group.

You have 8 gluons from $SU(3)$, 3 $W$ bosons from $SU_L(2)$ and 1 $B$ boson from $U_Y(1)$.
Those are all **charged under the respective group component** and uncharged under the other 2.

**2) Fermions**

Those are described by 2 different **massless** spinorial representations of the Poincare group, the so called **Weyl left/right handed spin-1/2 spinors**.

They also have **different representations under the 3 gauge groups**: depending on the representation each one gets **different charges**. It's messy so i will link you a table for this below.

**3) The Higgs scalar**

This is given by the scalar representation of Poincare group, so its a so called **spin-0 boson**.

This is also **charged**, depending on the representation, **under the 3 gauge groups.**

[image]

***MASSES AND INTERACTIONS***

**Gauge fields couple to fermions and scalars** through the covariant derivative which contains the interactions.
Gauge fields **self-interact when charged** under their groups.

If everything is massless how do we get masses for all the particles, neutrinos aside?

It's due to 3 main ingredients:

A) The **Higgs field has a mass** coming from its **self-interaction potential**.
This potential induces **symmetry breaking**, very important for fermions and gauge fields.

B) **Fermions**, neutrinos excluded,  **interact with each other and the Higgs field** via a very peculiar interaction: the **Yukawa interaction**.
When symmetry breaking of the Higgs occurs, **this interaction transforms into a mass component** for fermion fields.

C) The covariant derivate of the Higgs which contains the $W$ and $B$ **gauge boson-Higgs interactions** under symmetry breaking **breaks the gauge symmetry**. This breaking **changes the charges** of the group, mixes the 3 types of $W$ and the $B$ fields giving **3 massive fields**, $W^{\pm}$ and $Z$, and **1 massless field**, the EM $A$.

The **gluons are untouched** so they **remain massless**.

***THE SYMMETRY BREAKING***

The phenomenon of symmetry breaking is a complex phenomenon recurring often in physics.

In the standard model is induced by the Higgs boson.

The **Higgs potential depends** on the **energy scale** of the universe.

When the **energy goes under the electroweak scale**, it becomes **instable** and so you have symmetry breaking.

The **vacuum state obtains a VeV**, and the interactions with this VeV **give masses to the particles**.

The Goldstone bosons are a complex topic and since it seems to me that you don't have the correct mathematical background i don't want to go deep into that.

In short terms, **massless gauge fields have 2 polaritazions**.
Symmetry breaking generates **Goldstone bosons** which make up **the third polarization** which **massive gauge fields** have but massless miss.

Comment: I'm sorry for the hand-written picture, it wasn't meant for sharing but i don't have time to copy it in latex for an answer :')

Comment: Do you think this answer is at the appropriate level?

Comment: I don't know, the OP accepted it so i guess it is, if the OP doesn't understand one of the 3 sections is free to ask for more explanations and i will add them. I can't give a full course on the SM in a single post :)

Comment: That is brilliant! Just as I suspected, way beyond my level. Yet I wanted to lightly tap into the surface of particle physics to "understand" just the essence of it.  Which course is recommended to pursue the study of this for my higher studies? and in which academic level did you gain access to most of what you have explained to me today?

Comment: @AdityaPDJ if you still miss some points feel free to ask :) I have just finished a graduate/master physics degree (in Italy it's the end of a 5 years route). The courses I took are 3 courses on quantum field theory. Two on general quantum field theory and one dedicated to electroweak theory and standard model. I also took a course on group theory, all of this in my first year of master, namely the 4th year after Italian high school.

Comment: Oh Congratulations! I im going to be starting my grade 12 this week and from where im from, the bachelors course is of 4 years with quantum physics being taught only in the 4th year. Masters is im sure a 2 year course in Nepal so I might take your subjects into account. Was your bachelors similar
(we have 1st year; Mechanics, Thermodynamics, Statistical Physics, Electricity and Magnetism
2nd year; Optics, Modern Physics, Electronics
3rd year; Classical Mechanics
4th year; Quantum Mechanics ) ?

Comment: @LolloBoldo I will make sure to ask things I find interesting or troublesome! You seem quite frankly like someone I can look upto. Thank you for the responses so far

Comment: @AdityaPDJ yes it was quite similar, maybe we have a bit more math but overall quite similar. Good luck on your studying path :)